# Roots Of Unity:How to evaluate $\sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }\frac{α^k }{2-α^k} $?

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $α_k$,$k=1$ to $n$ be the n th roots of unity.How to evaluate $$\sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }\frac{α^k  }{2-α^k} $$?

I have no idea how to start the sum.Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1**
$$\frac{\alpha_k}{2-\alpha_k}=\frac{\alpha_k-2}{2-\alpha_k}+\frac{2}{2-\alpha_k}$$

**Hint 2** Let $P(x)=x^n-1$. Then
$$\frac{P'(x)}{P(x)} =\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x-\alpha_k}$$

Comment: Extremely elegant.Loved it :-)! Thank you so much :-D!

Comment: @N.S. Hint 1:  Yes.  Hint 2: How does that work?  The sum depends on $\alpha$, but $P'/P$ does not.

Comment: @Dr.MV $\alpha_1,..,\alpha_k$ are the roots of $P(x)$. You can write $$P(x)=(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)...(x-\alpha_n)$$

Comment: @N.S.  Apology.  I don't know how I  missed that; it's in the title.